# How to read n sentences after inputting n (solved) (C++)

Tags: c++, string, cpu-word, sentence

I need to input n, an integer, which is the number of sentences i need to input afterwards which are separated by enter, each one being on a new line.

Then i need to output the sentence which had the most words.

When i run the following program, i can only read n and then the program terminates.

EDIT 1:
I put a `cin.ignore()` after the `cin >> n` and it fixed the issue, but now when i output `text2` it only shows the first word of the sentence it should show.

EDIT 2:
i copied `text` into `aux` before splitting the sentence and then in the `if()` i copied `aux` into `text2`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//ifstream fin("X.TXT");
/**
ifstream gin("Y.TXT");
**/
//ofstream fout("BAC.TXT");

int main()
{
    int n, i, cnt1=0, cnt2=0;
    char text[256], text2[256]="";
    char *p;
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cnt1 = 0;
        cin.get(text, 256);
        p = strtok(text, " ");
        while(p != NULL)
        {
            cnt1++;
            p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        if(cnt1 > cnt2)
        {
            cnt2 = cnt1;
            strcpy(text2, text);
        }
    }
    cout << text2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you figured it out, you should post an "answer" below, and click the checkmark next to it. This will automatically mark your question as solved, no need to add anything to the title.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `cin` reads until a space character too, not only until newline '\n'. To read entire sentences use `istream& getline(char*, int size, char='\n')` instead. Note that the delimiting character parameter is newline by default, so it can be omitted, or set to anything you want.

"The terminator(or delimiter) character can be any character (like ‘ ‘, ‘, ‘ or any special character, etc.). The terminator character is read but not saved into a buffer, instead it is replaced by the null character." (Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getline-function-character-array/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//ifstream fin("X.TXT");
/**
ifstream gin("Y.TXT");
**/
//ofstream fout("BAC.TXT");

int main()
{
    int n, i, cnt1=0, cnt2=0;
    char text[256], text2[256]="";
    char *p;
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cnt1 = 0;
        //// Modification ////
        cin.getline(text, 256, '\n');
        //// End of modification ////
        p = strtok(text, " ");
        while(p != NULL)
        {
            cnt1++;
            p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        if(cnt1 > cnt2)
        {
            cnt2 = cnt1;
            strcpy(text2, text);
        }
    }
    cout << text2;
    return 0;
}
```